# How to select the ancestors of an xml node using xpath in matlab

Tags: xml, matlab, xpath

I have a xml file and want to select the ancestors name of each leaf node using the Xpath in matlab, I have tried to do it by every time I get 0 ancestors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taxonomy>
    <concept name="con1">
        <concept name="con11">
            <concept name="con1033990258">
                <concept name="con271874239">
                    <concept name="con1657241849">
                        <concept name="con1448945150"> 
                            <instance name="inst686829093"/>
                            <instance name="inst1379512917"/>
                            <instance name="inst2072196703"/>
                        </concept>
                   </concept>
              </concept>
        </concept>
        <concept name="con12">
         <instance name="inst2072192589"/>
        </concept>
        <concept name="con13"></concept>
        <concept name="con14"></concept>
    </concept>
</taxonomy>
```

And this is how I tried, I first stored all the instances name in in the instance_matrix which is a string matrix. Then for each instance, I looked for it ancestors but every time I get 0 and it's not right. As example the number of ancestors of the Instance ="inst686829093" would be 6 but me I get 0.

```
        Instances    =  xDoc.getElementsByTagName('instance');
        InstanceName =  char(Instances.item(0).getAttribute('name'));
        instance_matrix  = strings(Instances.getLength,1);
        IncestorList     =strings(Instances.getLength,100);
        for i= 0:Instances.getLength-1
            instance_matrix(i+1)=string(Instances.item(i).getAttribute('name'));
        end
        
            
        for i= 0:Instances.getLength-1
             expression   =   xpath.compile('//ancestor-or-self::instance[@name="' + instance_matrix(i+1) + '"]');
             Incestor =   expression.evaluate(xDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
             for j = 0:Incestor.getLength-1
                  IncestorList(i+1,j+1) = char(Incestor.item(j).getAttribute('name'));
             end
        end
```

If anyone could help me, I would be very grateful thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting `@name` attributes of all ancestors of `inst686829093` with `lxml`and `xpath`

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('test.xml')
>>> anc = tree.xpath('//instance[@name="inst686829093"]/ancestor::*/@name')
>>> anc
['con1', 'con11', 'con1033990258', 'con271874239', 'con1657241849', 'con1448945150']
```

Comment: So Matlab can run Python?

Comment: I don't know mathlab but the key part of the answer is the xpath expression that can be applied with any decent xpath implementation.

Comment: Thank you much, the path experssion works in matlab.

Comment: You can accept the answer if you want :-)